# Laptop with hybrid GPUs

Tags: amd

I have a Lenovo Z51-70 with Intel integrated graphics and an AMD R9 M375X. I have several GPU related questions:
What kind of drivers do I have to install?
Where from?
How can I set which GPU is used?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you still looking for solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo flex 4 with an i7 and AMD M465 (I think without double checking). I spent some time trying to force GPU usage and many remedies I found broke the windows drivers. OpenGL seems to be what works for now. Again, I broke the windows drivers a few times until I gave up and settled for OpenGL [but here is the page for official AMD support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux) and documentation. I would only attempt if you are willing to fix your machine in CLI or reformat if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

what graphics card do you have? The answer to your question depends on that

try using lspci | grep VGA to check it and either screenshot it or write the result back and I'll post an aswer to what you need to do